# App not appearing in iMessage extension drawer

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

This is perplexing me and I am not sure why this is happening. Only on 1 device, my app's extension does not seem to appear in the bottom drawer. This was not the case until the device was updated to iOS 11. Extension seems to appear and work as expected on other devices (including iOS 11).

Suddenly the problem seems to be with this one device. The main app seems to get installed and work fine, the problem is only with the iMessage Extension.

Any ideas what could I be missing here? From the screenshot my app is missing in red block.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the root cause of this was. I simply deleted the app from phone, rebooted the phone, closed and relaunched XCode, and build and run again. It appears to have come back and functioning normal.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has the issue of an iMessage extension not appearing on a physical device, the following worked for me:

1. Quit iMessages (through app switcher)
2. On the Xcode toolbar go to Product -> Install
3. The extension should now appear.

If this doesn't work, try restarting the phone after step 1.